# How to authenticate Google Appegine (Python) Remote API access if the 'access for less secure apps' is enabled?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, google-authentication

My google settings forbid an  'access for less secure apps'. Basically I enabled the 2-factor authentication.

I want to run the perform some tasks on my appengine instance using the remote api. see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi

- My app.yaml contains the following

`builtins:
- appstats: on #/_ah/stats/
- remote_api: on #/_ah/remote_api/`

- I run this piece of code: 
  `remote_api_shell.py -s <app name>.appspot.com #/_ah/remote_api/`
- I fill my email address and the password generated by https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords?pli=1

[image: 2-factor authentication, generate a new password]

- I receive an error message stating that `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

---

**MY QUESTION:** How could I run the remote api while using the 2-factor authentication? I would say that Google never envisaged this use case